# Git flow release branch

Tags: git, github, github-actions, git-flow

I'm implementing git flow on my company and with [this collection](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/index.html), but on github there's a behavior that I couldn't work with on github actions workflow.

When starting a new release, `git flow release start 1.0.0` the branch is created as `release/1.0.0`. This happened only when I started a fresh repo with git flow, all the others repos where created on bitbucket and later imported to github.

Those others imported came with branch name `release` and the version were tags.

The trigger on the workflow file is:

```
name: Release

on:
  push:
    branches: [ release ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ release ]
```

But I've already tried, [based on the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions):

```
[ release/*.*.* ]
[ release/* ]
[ release/1.0.0 ]
```

None worked, for a workaround I deleted the weird branch and created a `release` branch.

Answer (score 0):

How about this using `**`?

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'release/**'
```

Ref: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-including-branches-and-tags

Comment: Actually looks like this pattern only works for the release feature of github, not a regex for a branch name.